# Como crear un método que añada un listener y permita añadir código JAVA

Tags: java

Llevo ya varios días intentado hacer un sistema de eventos pero no encuentro la forma de hacer lo siguiente.

No encuentro la forma de hacer que se pueda interactuar con el evento desde un método, me refiero a esto:

```
api.addUserCreateMessageEvent(event->{
CÓDIGO
);
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo, me gustaría que cuando se lanzase el evento a los listeners en ese método pudiese yo añadir mi código.

Soy relativamente nuevo en Java y aún me cuesta este tipo de cosas.

Tengo estas 5 clases actualmente:

Esta interfaz corresponde al Listener, la que va a recibir el evento.

```
public interface UserCreateMessageListener extends GloballyAttachableListener {

    void fire();

}
```

Implementación de la anterior.

```
public class UserCreateMessageListenerImpl implements UserCreateMessageListener {
    @Override
    public void fire() {
        //CODIGO
    }
}
```

Esta interfaz contendrá los métodos para añadir listeners y recibir el evento añadiendo código (lo que pretendo buscar en el ejemplo de arriba del todo)

```
public interface GloballyAttachableListener {
    default void addUserCreateMessageEvent(UserCreateMessageListener listener) {
        //Añado los listeners a mi inicializador de listeners
    }
}
```

Esta clase dispara los eventos a los listeners declarados.

```
public class Initializer extends ListenerAdapter{
    private static List<UserCreateMessageListener> listeners = new ArrayList<UserCreateMessageListener>();

    public static void addListener(UserCreateMessageListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        for (UserCreateMessageListener e : listeners) {
            e.fire();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta clase es la clase desde la cual pretendo obtener información y eventos.

```
public interface Api extends GloballyAttachableListener{

    default String getPrefix() {
        return ConfigAccessor.getPrefix();
    }

    default long getId() {
        return ConfigAccessor.getId();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el código de las clases que mencionas, para que podamos ayudarte. Y qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: He añadido los códigos ya. El api.addListener hace referencia al método que hay en mi GloballyAttachableListener.

Comment: "Tengo creada una clase que es la que contiene la información del evento. Otra clase que es la interfaz del listener, y otra clase que es la implementación del listener." Para entender mejor tu intencion con el código, especifica que clase hace que cosa. En vez de decir "tengo una clase que contiene la info..." puedes decir "La clase `Foo` contiene la info". Asi es mas facil entender tu codigo

Comment: @AndresGardiol Perdón, no suelo escribir mucho en relación a consultas de código. Espero que ahora esté mejor.

Comment: No hay por qué pedir perdón, todos estamos aprendiendo :)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310117/how-to-create-a-method-that-adds-a-listener-and-allows-adding-java-code/65310338#65310338

Esta solucionado en ese enlace, por si alguno busca solución.